# can a gas comission be paid by the owner?

Tags: transactions, gas

I want to create a token but, I want people to send the tokens without them paying for the gas, is there any command to do this

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is possible and is already implemented in many token smart contracts, for example in [Stasis EURS Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8#code).  There are also ERCs for this: [ERC-865](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8#code), [ERC-1228](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865).
The idea is than token holder digitally signs transfer order, but, instead of sending it to the smart contract directly, gives it to a third party called “relayer”.  The relayer forwards the order to the smart contract and pays for gas.  Smart contract verifies digital signature in the order to ensure it is authentic and transfers tokens from token holder's balance.